# task error in ssis data flow for csv import

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I exported some data using sqlplus in Windows server to a csv file.

I'm trying to import the csv file into sql server using SSIS but get this error:

```
[OLE DB Destination [1743]] Error: An error occurred while setting up
a binding for the "TECHNOLOGY" column. The binding status was  
"DT_TEXT". The data flow column type is
"DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION". The conversion from the OLE DB
type of "DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN" to the destination column type of
"DBTYPE_VARCHAR" might not be supported by this provider.
```

The destination table was created using the ddl from the oracle table and in my data flow task in SSIS the varchar columns are DT_TEXT datatype. In the dest table, they are varchar(10) and in oracle, they were also varchar(10)

I tried using derived column with this expression:
(DT_STR,12,1252)[Column 1]

but get this error then:

```
[OLE DB Destination [1770]] Error: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the     "TECHNOLOGY" column. The binding status was "DT_TEXT". The data flow column type is "DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION". The conversion from the OLE DB type of "DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN" to the destination column type of "DBTYPE_VARCHAR" might not be supported by this provider.
```

any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2):

Right click your source transformation in the data flow and go to the advanced editor. There will be a list of columns there that shows the output of the source including the data type. Verify that it is outputting the column as text and ensure that any derived column outputs or other transformations you have along the way are not modify or replacing the data type.

If necessary, insert a derived column transformation before your destination and replace the column and force it to be text.

Also verify your mapping of column to destination column in the outbound data flow to ensure it is being mapped as you are expecting it to be.

Comment: so when I right click and go to advance editor, I go to the tab called "input output properties", in there I see "flat file source output" and then in there I see "external columns" and "output columns". In both the datatype is "text stream [DT_TEXT]"

Comment: f you exported with SQLPLUS it probably added a load of trailing blanks to your last column, which means the CSV driver thinks it's an enormous TEXT column. Open your CSV file, go to the last column and see if it has put trailing blanks in it. You need to work out a way to trim those off in your export process, or you need to perhaps try trimming them first in SSIS.

Comment: @user2061886 Put a data viewer on the data flow coming directly after your source and try looking to see what the data appears like for that column